# udf declaration for 2 lists and/or 1 2D array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I would like to declare a udf that returns a 2 1D arrays or 1 2D array (an example of both would be nice).  I know that this works for 1D:

```py
@udf("array<int>")
```

However I have tried many variants of this such as the following with no luck:

```py
@udf("array<int>,array<int>")
@udf("array<int>","array<int>")
@udf("array<int,int>")
etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

To return two lists you can use a `struct`

```py
@udf("struct<_1: array<int>, _2: array<int>>")
```

or

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructField, StructType, IntegerType 

@udf(StructType([
    StructField("_1", ArrayType(IntegerType())),
    StructField("_2", ArrayType(IntegerType()))]))
```

where function should return (PEP 484 [typing notation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html))

```py
Tuple[List[int], List[int]]
```

i.e.

```py
return [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
```

To return two-dimensional array declare:

```py
@udf("array<array<int>>")
```

or

```py
@udf(ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
```

where function should return

```py
List[List[int]]
```

i.e.

```py
return [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

If you return array of fixed size tuple

```py
List[Tuple[int, int]]
```

i.e.

```py
return  [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

the schema should be

```py
@udf("array<struct<_1: int, _2: int>>")
```

or

```py
@udf(ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("_1", IntegerType()),
    StructField("_2", IntegerType())])))
```

though `array<array<int>>`, albeit not canonical, should work in that case as well.

**Note**:

The choice of names used above (`_1` and `_2`) is arbitrary can can be adjust according to your requirements.

Comment: @user1624577 If you need any additional explanations please let me know, and I'll provide necessary edit.